# my output is showing the tkinter widget error and button error and not displaying the button

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-text, tkinter-button

the following was my code for creating to do list application

```py
from tkinter import ...
// i have just not mentioned all imports   
root = Tk()
root.title("My Todo List App") 
root.configure(background="light green")   
root.geometry("550x500")    
root.resizable(width=False , height=False)   
title_label = ttk.Label(root, text="Title",background="light green",font=("TkDefaultFont",16))
title_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
title_text = StringVar()
title_entry = ttk.Entry(root, width=25, textvariable=title_text)
title_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)
add_btn = Button(root, text="Add Task", bg="blue", fg="white", font="helvetica 1- bold", command="")
add_btn.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=W)

       root.mainloop()
```

the error I got in visual studio code on running the above code is:

```
C:\Users\tkurd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe C:/Users/tkurd/Desktop/todolist/todo.py
  
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\tkurd\Desktop\todolist\todo.py", line 22, in <module>
    add_btn = Button(root, text="Add Task", bg="blue", fg="white", font="helvetica 1- bold", command="")

 File "C:\Users\tkurd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2650, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'button', cnf, kw)

 File "C:\Users\tkurd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2572, in __init__
    self.tk.call(
        _tkinter.TclError: expected integer but got "1-"

 Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

when specifying fonts in Tkinter, we don't include hyphens (-). Only use spaces, and the text should only be a) the font size b) the font name c) either bold, italic, or underline.

so replace line 23 with:
`add_btn = Button(root, text="Add Task", bg="blue", fg="white", font="helvetica 1 bold", command="")`

Note: it may look like the button's text has disappeared, but it's just that the font size is 1.

Comment: thanks. I thought that it was major mistake‍♂️